# am i able to reference environment variables in go templates?

Tags: thoughtworks-go

Trying to reference environment variables from go templates but i don't think it's possible? Can't see anything in the documentation and the examples I've pawed through use parameters aplenty but never an environment variable. What I'd like is something like

```
<templates>
<pipeline name="TestEcho">
  <stage name="Echo">
    <jobs>
      <job name="Echo">
        <tasks>
          <exec command="echo ${SOME_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE}">
          </exec>
        </tasks>
      </job>
    </jobs>
  </stage>
</pipeline>
<templates>
```

Thanks in advance!

Tim

Comment: Sorry guys. Wrong GO. Using ThoughtWorks' GO product for build pipelines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can !

You should use **%SOME_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE%** instead of ${SOME_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE} (on a *windows* agent).

I guess you are using a windows agent. Thoughtworks' documentation is Linux focused, which is why their example is not working for you.

You can use all [Go Standard environment variables](http://www.go.cd/documentation/user/current/faq/dev_use_current_revision_in_build.html) in your tasks.

You can set environment variables at :

- the environment level
- the pipeline level (override environment level)
- the stage level (override pipeline level)

You can use all those environment variables in your task :

```xml
<pipeline name="TestEcho">
  <stage name="Echo">
    <jobs>
      <job name="Echo">
        <tasks>
          <exec command="echo %SOME_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE%">
          </exec>
        </tasks>
      </job>
    </jobs>
  </stage>
</pipeline>
```

You can set the environment variable at the environment level :

```xml
<environments>
  <environment name="SomeEnvironment">
    <environmentvariables>
      <variable name="SomeVariable">
        <value>SomeValue</value>
      </variable>
    </environmentvariables>
    <pipelines>
      <pipeline name="TestEcho" />
    </pipelines>
  </environment>
</environments>
```

You can set the environment variable at the pipeline level :

```xml
<pipeline name="TestEcho">
  <environmentvariables>
    <variable name="SomeVariable">
      <value>SomeValue</value>
    </variable>
  </environmentvariables>
  <stage name="Echo">
    <jobs>
      <job name="Echo">
        <tasks>
          <exec command="echo %SomeVariable%">
          </exec>
        </tasks>
      </job>
    </jobs>
  </stage>
</pipeline>
```

You can set the environment variable at the stage level :

```xml
<pipeline name="TestEcho">
  <stage name="Echo">
    <jobs>
      <job name="Echo">
        <environmentvariables>
          <variable name="SomeVariable">
            <value>SomeValue</value>
          </variable>
        </environmentvariables>
        <tasks>
          <exec command="echo %SomeVariable%">
          </exec>
        </tasks>
      </job>
    </jobs>
  </stage>
</pipeline>
```

You can override an environment variable :

```xml
<pipeline name="TestEcho">
  <environmentvariables>
    <variable name="SomeVariable">
      <value>Value1</value>
    </variable>
  </environmentvariables>
  <stage name="Echo">
    <jobs>
      <job name="Echo">
        <environmentvariables>
          <variable name="SomeVariable">
            <value>Value2</value>
          </variable>
        </environmentvariables>
        <tasks>
          <exec command="echo %SomeVariable%"><!-- Write Value2 -->
          </exec>
        </tasks>
      </job>
      <job name="Echo2">
        <tasks>
          <exec command="echo %SomeVariable%"><!-- Write Value1 -->
          </exec>
        </tasks>
      </job>
    </jobs>
  </stage>
</pipeline>
```

[Source that helped me](http://lyricsoft.blogspot.fr/2012/10/how-to-build-and-publish-to-nuget-using.html)

Comment: Tom, can you tell me more ? What did you try ? How is your pipeline ? How did you set your environment variable ?

Comment: In the end I found I was able to refer to environment variables using ${VAR} or $VAR (but not %VAR% as you suggest) - but not between different stages in the pipeline, so it didn't do me much good anyway!

Comment: @TomMcIntyre, i added some details about how to set environment variables. Could you check if your configuration is similar ?

Comment: @TomMcIntyre, i bet you are using a linux agent. The syntax i suggested is for windows only. I am pretty sure ${SOME_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE} should work on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, this is not possible and only parameters can be referenced, using the `#{parameter_name}` syntax

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes found this out the hard way! In the end doesn't cause us too much pain that this is the case. Though it did cause me a lot of pain trying to make it happen!

Comment: You are wrong. This is possible, using the %environment_variable_name% syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. You just need to run it as a custom command task, using `/bin/bash` as the command, and `-c` as the first parameter to tell bash to expand the parameters.

So your pipeline config would look like this:

```
<templates>
<pipeline name="TestEcho">
  <stage name="Echo">
    <jobs>
      <job name="Echo">
        <tasks>
          <exec command="/bin/bash">
            <arg>-c</arg>
            <arg>echo ${SOME_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE}</arg>
          </exec>
        </tasks>
      </job>
    </jobs>
  </stage>
</pipeline>
<templates>
```

See here for similar: http://support.thoughtworks.com/entries/22628904-Custom-environment-variables-referencing-other-variables